# No Type or protocol named class `ChatInboxDelegate`

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, protocols

This class (`CustomViewCell.h`) throws  No Type or protocol named `ChatInboxDelegate` despite being defined in the file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ChatInboxDelegate;

@class ChatMessage;

@interface SHNChatEverydayMessageViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ChatInboxDelegate> delegate;

- (void) populate:(ChatMessage *)model;
+ (float) getHeight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) ChatMessage *chatMessage;

@end


@protocol ChatInboxDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)openViewController:(UIViewController *)vc;
- (void)reloadTable;
- (void)updateChatMessage : (NSString * )messageId  chatMessage:(ChatMessage *) chatMessage;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this code as is. Is it possible that you didn't save the file before building, or that there's something else in your code using the symbol `ChatInboxDelegate`?